# Confusion on read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) from class Reader

Tags: java

To my understanding, this abstract method reads characters into a portion of an array.

What confuses me is that it returns the number of character read, or -1 if it reaches the end of stream.

Does that mean that the read method read 1 character at a time and return the no. of character read, and then once it hits the end it returns -1?

E.g., if it's reading a string "abcd" form a txt file with read(cbuf, 0 4), it returns 1234 and finally -1?

And if that's the case, does that mean we can only access the read characters through cbuf?

edit2:
Thanks again everyone, I finally figured out everything. Cheers!

Comment: Please specify which `read` method you are talking about? The class name?

Comment: Hello Rohit, it's from class Reader. It's a abstract method and I'm trying to understand it since I have to write an extension class and implement this method. Without clearly understand what it does it's very difficult to get the implementation right...

Comment: You can go through [`BufferedReader#read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read(char[], int, int)) method implementation of that method to get an idea.

Comment: thanks alot rohit! so its repeatedly calling the read method!! thanks!

Comment: @IannWu: theoretically always reading exactly 1 character *would* be a valid (if not really optimal) implementation.

Comment: There are other implementation for that method too. If you are implementing this method, I would suggest you to go through all of them, to find out what really you want. And why are you implementing this method yourself?

Comment: Hi Rohit, I was working on problem set, that's why. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the read method (from various classes) will read up to a maximum of `len` characters in one operation. It might read fewer characters. You should check the return value of the function to know how many such characters it read.

Once it reaches the EOF, it will return -1.

Comment: are you saying that it does return the total number of characters read during each read?

Comment: Yes absolutely. That way you know if the method read fewer than the designated `len` number of characters. And if it returns -1 it means no characters were read, and you hit EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Documentation of BufferedReader.read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29):

> This method implements the general contract of the corresponding read
>   method of the Reader class. As an additional convenience, it attempts
>   to read as many characters as possible by repeatedly invoking the read
>   method of the underlying stream. This iterated read continues until
>   one of the following conditions becomes true:
>
> 1. The specified number of characters have been read
> 2. The read method of the underlying stream returns -1, indicating end-of-file.
> 3. The ready method of the underlying stream returns false, indicating that further
>      input requests would block.

...

> If the first read on the underlying stream
>   returns -1 to indicate end-of-file then this method returns -1.
>   Otherwise this method returns the number of characters actually read.

....

> Ordinarily this method takes characters from this stream's character
>   buffer, filling it from the underlying stream as necessary. If,
>   however, the buffer is empty, the mark is not valid, and the requested
>   length is at least as large as the buffer, then this method will read
>   characters directly from the underlying stream into the given array.

Comment: That **only** applies to `BufferedReader` and not necessarily to any other `Reader` implementation!