# How to read whole file with read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)

Tags: java, stream, bufferedstream

I've got this soure:

```
public static void inBufferBooks() throws IOException
{
    Reader inStreamBooks = null;
    BufferedReader bufferIn = null;

    try
    {
        inStreamBooks = new FileReader("Files/BufferBook.txt");
        bufferIn = new BufferedReader(inStreamBooks);

        char text[] = new char[10];

        int i = -1;

        while ((i = inStreamBooks.read(text, 0, 10)) != -1)
        {
            System.out.print(text);
        }
```

When I read file at the end of the text console printing chars who's fill last array.
How can I read whole text from the file without redundant chars from last array?

Comment: The variable ``i`` tells you how many characters have been read into your buffer. But you still print the whole array, not only the data from ``text[0]`` to ``text[i-1]``.

Comment: Use `ArrayList` or some other Collection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108624/confusion-on-readchar-cbuf-int-off-int-len-from-class-reader

Comment: What’s the point of `bufferIn = new BufferedReader(inStreamBooks);` when you are using the original `FileReader` afterwards? Note that if you would use the `BufferedReader` you’ve created, you could use its `readLine()` method which simplifies your task a lot…

Answer (score 0):

> How can I read whole text from the file without redundant chars from last array?

Use the value `read` returns to you to determine how many characters in the array are still valid. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read-char:A-int-int-):

> **Returns:**
>
> The number of characters read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember how may characters you read and only print that many.

```
for (int len; ((len = inStreamBooks.read(text, 0, text.length)) != -1; ) {
    System.out.print(new String(text, 0, len));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the problem I change my *while* cycle like this:

```
while((i = bufferText.read(text, 0, text.length)) != -1){
            if(text.length == i){
                System.out.print(text);
            }else if (text.length != i){
                    System.out.print(Arrays.copyOfRange(text, 0, i));
            }
```

Thanks everyone for the help.